# Why are implicit variables not initialized in Scala when called from unit test?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

Given the the following singleton Object in Scala:

```
package demo

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.io.StdIn

object WebServer extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("myActorSystem")
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val route = {
    path("api" / "done-as-promised") {
      get {
        complete {
          Future.successful("done")
        }
      }
    }
  }

  val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)

}
```

And the following unit test

```
package demo

import akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest
import org.scalactic.TypeCheckedTripleEquals
import org.scalatest.{Inspectors, Matchers, WordSpec}

class WebServerSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers with TypeCheckedTripleEquals with Inspectors with ScalatestRouteTest {

  "The WebServer /done-as-promised" should {
    "return done" in {
      // tests:
      Get("/api/done-as-promised") ~> WebServer.route ~> check {
        status.intValue() shouldEqual 200
        responseAs[String] shouldEqual "done"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> [ERROR] [04/19/2016 07:12:18.995]
>   [ScalaTest-run-running-WebServerSpec]
>   [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(demo-WebServerSpec)] Error during
>   processing of request
>   HttpRequest(HttpMethod(GET),http://example.com/api/done-as-promised,List(),HttpEntity.Strict(none/none,ByteString()),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$anonfun$handleExceptions$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ExecutionDirectives.scala:33)
>     at
>   akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ExecutionDirectives$$anonfun$handleExceptions$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ExecutionDirectives.scala:29)
>     at
>   akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.RouteTest$TildeArrow$$anon$1.apply(RouteTest.scala:162)
>     at
>   akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.RouteTest$TildeArrow$$anon$1.apply(RouteTest.scala:150)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out. The thing is: removing the `extends app` will make the test succeed.

The reason for the problem is that when `WebServer` is declared as `extends App`, it uses the `DelayedInit` functionality of the `App` trait.  Because of this, the initialization code in the contructor is **not** added to the constructor of the WebServer object. Instead is called when the `main` method is called on the WebServer. So when he references the "route" inside the tests, those are all coming up null.

Mixing in the `DelayedInit` trait (`App` extends from `DelayedInit`) will rewrite your class or object template. Instead of adding your val's and var's to the constructor, it will be added to the `def delayedInit(body: => Unit)` hook (inaccessible to user code). Apparently this one is called whenever the main method is called.

You can verify this by simply calling "main" on the WebServer inside the test.  If you do this, then the test will pass. This is because calling main triggers the initialization resulting in those objects being created.

Generally speaking though the right solution is probably to move the routing to somewhere else, rather than having it inside of the base App.